# Webscraping in R using CSS selector

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape some data off a shoe website called footlocker.com
I have the following code, where I am trying to extract the number of 'xyz' brand shoes on sale and the total number of those shoes.

```
library(rvest)
webpage <- 
read_html("https://www.footlocker.com/category/brands/adidas.html? 
query=adidas%3Arelevance%3AproductType%3A200005")
webpage

#Using CSS selectors to scrape the sale section
sale_count_html <- html_nodes(webpage, 'li:nth-child(1) .miscellaneous 
.count')
sale_count <- html_text(sale_count_html)
sale_count <- as.numeric(sale_count)
head(sale_count)


total_count_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'strong+ strong')
total_count <- html_text(total_count_html)
head(total_count)
```

It is giving me character(0) for sale_count whereas on the website it is a 3 digit number. And for total_count, it is giving me a totally different number than what is on the website

Comment: The web page probably loads data via javascript after it activates in the browser. Simple web scraping doesn't run javascript. Maybe you can use something like [RSelenium](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/) to run that code for you.

Comment: What you're actually doing is violating the terms of service — https://www.footlocker.com/help/terms-of-use.html — and encouraging others to do so and potentially end up in legal trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to extract the product names and product prices with the following code :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(stringr)
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate('https://www.footlocker.com/category/brands/adidas.html?query=adidas%3Arelevance%3AproductType%3A200005')

# The four lines below are to remove the pop-up windows 
webElem <- remDr$findElement("id", "bluecoreEmailCaptureSubmit")
webElem$submitElement()
webElem <- remDr$findElement("id", "touAgreeBtn")
webElem$ClickElement()

page_Content <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]

# Here, we extract the information related to the shoes with regular expressions
text <- str_extract(page_Content, "<span class=\"ProductName\"(.*)(\\$\\d{1,5}\\.\\d{0,2})")
text_Split <- strsplit(text, split = "<span class=\"ProductName\">")[[1]]
text_Split <- text_Split[-1]

product_Name <- str_extract_all(string = text_Split, pattern = "<span class=\"ProductName-primary\">[^<]*</span>")

pattern_Product_Price <- c("(<span class=\"ProductPrice\"><span>\\$\\d{1,5}\\.\\d{0,2})",
                           "(<span class=\"ProductPrice-final\" aria-hidden=\"true\">\\$\\d{1,5}\\.\\d{0,2})",
                          "(<span class=\"ProductPrice-original\" aria-hidden=\"true\">\\$\\d{1,5}\\.\\d{0,2})")

regex_Product_Price <- paste0(pattern_Product_Price, collapse = "|")
  
product_Price <- str_extract_all(string = text_Split, pattern = regex_Product_Price)
```

From this information, you can count the number of pairs of shoes.